# How to add code between two spans using post method?

Tags: javascript, php

My problem is to add new code between two spans using php post method. I have two files one have the code to post. code input feild will have the php code and then select the position. if i select position one the code will be postedon position one in createfile.php if i select position 2 the code will pasted at postion two. please ignore the code i want just to clear the logic here is my code example.

`<form method="POST" action="createfile.php">`

```
<input type="text" name="code">
<select name="position">
<option value="pos1">Position 1</option>
<option value="pos2">Position 1</option>
</select>
```

createfile.php

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$position =$_POST['position'];
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span>postion 1</span>
<span>position 2</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be what you want

```
<body>
    <span>position 1 : <?php if($_POST['position'] == 1) echo $_POST['code']; ?></span>
    <span>position 2 : <?php if($_POST['position'] == 2) echo $_POST['code']; ?></span>
</body>
```